# Alternative way than euclidean distance to compute likelihoods

Tags: euclidean-distance

I am currently having a part of code using euclidean distance to compute some likelihoods. I am trying to think of any ways to compute likelihoods with the same effectiveness, without using euclidean distance. 
Is there anyone who could give me maybe a hint for a different way?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are looking for; you could leave out the square root which is usually involved computing the distance.

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient context. In some contexts whatever formula you are using might be almost forced on you (e.g. if it is a maximum likelihood estimator for a particular distribution). In other contexts you are doing something more heuristic and have the freedom to experiment with other metrics such as the computationally easier taxicab metric.

Comment: In my first post I said that I want to find a different way to compute likelihoods with the same effectiveness with the euclidean, because as I found while searching, other methods like taxicab/manhattan metric doesn't always compute the min distance, while euclidean does.